# In Angular2 *ngFor loop cannot create canvas elements from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, angular

In my TypeScript class I can load an array of type HTMLCanvasElement - but when I iterate over this array with ngFor - I only see text on the page for each canvas object loaded: "[object HTMLCanvasElement]".

The gist of my template code:

```
<div>*ngFor="#cvs of canvases">  
{{cvs}} </div>
```

Relevant Class code:

```
canvases:HTMLCanvasElement[]=[]
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
//here I take an image and drawimage via context -- this part works
//then......
this.canvases.push(canvas);
```

My assumption is probably wrong-headed: but, if you can append a canvas object to a node (which I can do) - then why can you not place the canvas object onto the window "directly" inside a div using *ngFor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a componenet with image and other options required as @Input()
- Move your canvas creation code in the component
- In the component you have shown make canvases an array of objects that contains the information for each canvas
- In ngFor render the canvas component you created by passing info to your component

Your code is not working because you are trying to stringify the HTMLCanvasElement inside ngFor using interpolation {{}}

Here is the working Plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/1ho41z

- Instead of push html objects around use javascript objects.
- Let HTML create HTML elements instead of using `document.createElement`
- Avoid using document.getElementById inside Angular component
- See usage of View Child to get hold of components

There is still scope of improvements in the plunker, but you get the gist of creating a component in Angular with the plunk above

Comment: Thanks for your help, Siraj - Could you clarify a few things for me? In your first bullet - are you saying "Create an ADDITIONAL component? Second bullet: "Move your canvas creation code INTO the NEW Component? A simple but clear example would really help - thanks!

Comment: Create a plunker with current code, I help you modify

Comment: I am reviewing your plunker
Tip: If you are using anything like `document.getElementById` inside angular component - Just know that this is wrong and there could be Angular-ish way to do this.

Comment: `document.createElement("canvas")` inside Angular Component is also strict no - no

Comment: Thanks, Siraj! I am eager to learn - I had added this hack just to try and get the canvases on the page - but that is why I do want to learn the Angular2 way - and want to understand how or even if I can take canvas elements from an array and place them into the window using *ngFor - Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me, Siraj - I see it very differently now!